# jQuery: click event called $('textarea').val().trim().length times

Tags: jquery, html, events, click, keydown

Well, that's pretty much what happens.

We've all seen this before: button becomes active **and clickable** only after we've put something in an input filed. I'm trying to implement that. I guess either I've gone the wrong way and I should've placed my jQuery selectors differently, or it's just something wrong with the code.

```
$('textarea').bind({'keyup' : function(){
    if ($(this).val().trim().length){
        $('.send-feedback').removeClass('inactive').click(function(){
            console.log('clicked');
        });
    } else {
        $('.send-feedback').addClass('inactive').off('click');
    }
}})
```

Basically, I see 'clicked' in the console multiple times, but if I add `console.log('key pressed')` before the `if` check, it's being shown once per keydown, as expected.

Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may as well just set the button to `disabled`. This will prevent the `click` event from firing:

```
if($('textarea').val().trim().length > 0)
    $('.send-feedback').removeAttr('disabled');
else
    $('.send-feedback').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Then separate your `click` function:

```
$('textarea').on('input', function(){ ... });
$('.send-feedback').on('click', function() { ... });
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3CdEV/).

> thing is, it's not really a button, but an `<a>`

In that case you can use classes, which I suppose is sort of what you're currently doing:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="send-feedback disabled">Click</a>
```

JavaScript textarea length check:

```
if( $(this).val().trim().length > 0 )
    $('.send-feedback').removeClass('disabled');
else
    $('.send-feedback').addClass('disabled');
```

JavaScript click function:

```
$('.send-feedback').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
        return;

    alert('Clicked!');
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3CdEV/1/).

Comment: thing is, it's not really a button, but an <a>. Also, wouldn't an IDE highlight the last line because of a duplicate jQuery selector?

Comment: You should have specified that in your question. Let me just update my answer.

Comment: No need to, Richard has already aswered, I'm just waiting to accept his answer. On the other hand, `attr` and `removeAttr` will surely come in handy later. Thank you for helping me learn :)

Comment: @Loki I've added a second JSFiddle example.

Comment: I'll take a look at both. and yeah, since I'm not using buttons, I've no other option but to use classes

Comment: The button shouldn't be clickable if it's disabled. that's why I've tried to use `on` and `off` methods inside the other handler. please, cite Richard's answer please, and I'll accept this one

Comment: Well `.on()` is preferred over `.bind()`, as I've used above. Depending on which jQuery version you're using you may want to incorporate that.

Comment: @Loki the `.hasClass()` check I've used within the `on('click')` function prevents further code execution. Try it yourself: the `alert()` won't work unless the `textarea` has text within.

Comment: ...and a simple `a.disabled { color:#f00; text-decoration:none; cursor:default; }` would achieve the same styling affect: http://jsfiddle.net/3CdEV/2/

Answer (score 2):

You are rebinding the click event on every keyup event.

Change the code to check that the button is inactive before binding the click by adding `.inactive` to the selector:

```
$('textarea').bind({'keyup' : function(){
    if ($(this).val().trim().length){
        $('.send-feedback.inactive').removeClass('inactive').click(function(){
            console.log('clicked');
        });
    } else {
        $('.send-feedback').addClass('inactive').off('click');
    }
}})
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/uEyRM/)

Comment: that solves the problem perfectly, thank you, I'll accept the answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you enter a letter (keyup), you add the event click to `.send-feedback`.

If you have many `.send-feedback`, you'll have

> (nbr of chars in textarea) * (number of .send-feedback)

times the "clicked" text appear.

You should only add the click event if the `.send-feedback` has the class "inactive".

Here :

```
$('textarea').bind({'keyup' : function(){
    if ($(this).val().trim().length) {
        if ($('.send-feedback').hasClass('inactive')){
            $('.send-feedback').removeClass('inactive').click(function(){
                console.log('clicked');
            });
        }
    } else {
        $('.send-feedback').addClass('inactive').off('click');
    }
}})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sadly it repeats the previous one :)

Comment: "It repeat the previous one" meaning the code is incorrect, or it repeat a previous answer (because if it's the former, I don't know where but I can fix it, for the later, well, too late for me ;))

Answer (score 0):

I've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMrd4/) for you, I hope it will help:

It goes like this:

```
var el = $(this);
var btn = $("#btnDoStuff");

if(el.val().length > 0)
    btn.prop("disabled", false);
else
    btn.prop("disabled", true);
```

I hope I didn't misunderstood the issue.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't help. thank you for your time though